# How to get username element text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

So I want to take the text of username from div class.

The html page:

```
<div id="gridview-1030" class="x-grid-view x-fit-item x-grid-view-default x-unselectable"
style="overflow: auto; margin: 0px; width: 549px; height: 218px;" tabindex="-1">
<table class="x-grid-table x-grid-table-resizer" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:549px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="x-grid-header-row">
            <th class="x-grid-col-resizer-gridcolumn-1019" style="width: 69px; height: 0px;"></th>
            <th class="x-grid-col-resizer-gridcolumn-1020" style="width: 69px; height: 0px;"></th>
            <th class="x-grid-col-resizer-gridcolumn-1021" style="width: 69px; height: 0px;"></th>
            <th class="x-grid-col-resizer-gridcolumn-1022" style="width: 69px; height: 0px;"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="x-grid-row x-grid-row-selected x-grid-row-focused">
            <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1019   x-grid-cell-first">
                <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">username</div>
            </td>
            <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1020   ">
                <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">firstname</div>
            </td>
            <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1021   ">
                <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">lastname</div>
            </td>
            <td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1022   ">
                <div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: left; ;">full name</div>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I tried using the xpath like below but it didnt work

```
user = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="gridview-1030"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div").text
```

I got an error saying:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="gridview-1030"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div"}
```

Please help me fix it thanks.

Comment: can you please add little bit more code to help us understand the issue better ?

Comment: There is no element with `@id="gridview-1030"` in your HTML. Post full HTML, or confirm the url of the page you're trying to scrape.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus code updated now check

Comment: if the answers below don't work, post the error you receive.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus getting blank results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not test it, as it's impossible without the url in question, however the following should work:

```
[..]
## add the following to your imports
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
[..]
## define driver, then
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

desired_info  = [x.text for x in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="gridview-1030"]//tr/td[1]/div')))]
```

See [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) for more details.